# Martingale & Ito Integral Help

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I have seen a few textbooks that say $ \int_{0}^{t} W_{s}ds$ is NOT a martingale. I believe they are correct, but I'm confused what is wrong with the logic below that seems to show it is a martingale. Could anyone tell me where I went wrong?

By Ito's Lemma:

$$
\int_0^t W_s ds = tW_t - \int_0^t sdW_s
$$

Simplifying gives:

$$
\int_0^t W_s ds
 = \int_0^t t dW_s - \int_0^t s dW_s
 = \int_0^t (t-s) dW_s
$$

And $\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)dW_{s} $ is an Ito Integral which is a martingale, so $ \int_{0}^{t} W_{s}ds$ must be a martingale.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's incorrect to say $\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)dW_{s} $ is an Ito Integral since it's not only a function of s in the integral but also t?

Comment: The process $(t-s)$ is not progressively measurable/adapted.

Comment: This is a fancy way of saying what you've said in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $s< t$ and write
$$
\int_0^t W_r\,dr=\int_0^sW_r\,dr+\int_s^t W_r\,dr.
$$
Then
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\int_0^t W_r\,dr\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right]=\int_0^sW_r\,dr+\mathsf{E}\left[\int_s^t W_r\,dr\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right],
$$
where $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is the underlying filtration, and
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\int_s^t (W_r-W_s+W_s)\,dr\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right]=(t-s)W_s\ne 0.
$$